# Make nordic behave differently when it is not receiving data

Tags: c, wifi

I am looking for some help with the [Nordic wifi](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8602) .

The situation i have got corrected is :

When the Nordic is receiving data is randomly glows the leds which are activated by allrandom and the led_strip_color methods .

However there is a situation when the Nordic is not receiving any data , and i donot want to use my power during that time , i want all the leds to be turned of ///

```
 while(!(nrf24l01_irq_pin_active() && nrf24l01_irq_rx_dr_active()));
```

The above command checks if the nordic is active and receiving data , however when i stop sending data it is unavble to execute the command mentioned in there .

The commented out sections are the things i have tried however i am not able to figure a way out .

```
while (1) {
    nrf24l01_clear_flush(); // Clears the wifi cache

    nrf24l01_set_as_rx(true); // sets the wifi pin as high
    while(!(nrf24l01_irq_pin_active() && nrf24l01_irq_rx_dr_active())); //checks if it //inactive and loops in that state 
    /*{
    printf(" test nordic wait");
    led_strip_colors[0] = 0xFF0000;  // red // colors each led in led strip
    led_strip_colors[1] = 0;  // green
    led_strip_colors[2] = 0;  // green
    led_strip_colors[3] = 0;  // green
    led_strip_colors[4] = 0;  // green
    led_strip_colors[5] = 0;  // green
    led_strip_colors[6] = 0;  // green
    led_strip_colors[7] = 0;  // green
    led_strip_colors[8] = 0;  // green
    led_strip_colors[9] = 0;  // green
    led_strip_colors[10] = 0;  // green
     //ds_delay_uS(100);
      //for (n = 0; n < LED_STRIP_LEN; n++) { led_strip_colors[n] = 0; }


    }*/
    nrf24l01_read_rx_payload(rxdata, 32);// collects data in rxdata

    ping_count++;                  
    nrf24l01_irq_clear_all();
    printf("%s\n", rxdata);

    if ((ping_count % 10) == 0) {
      addRandom();  // helps to change color randomly
    }
    send_frame();   

    ds_delay_uS(130);
    int i;
    // Delay for 1 second
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
      ds_delay_uS(100);
    }
  }
}
```

I have another nordic active which sends data continuously . 
Any help would appreciated** 
*** I am trying to make a GeoCacher which will glow when it receives data from a key-fob , this is a part of it ***

Comment: You may need to provide some sort of link, so that we know what you mean by "nordic" here!

Comment: Thanks for that , https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8602 is the link to the product